# Why does an OPTIONS request fail when the answer to the follow up request is a 204?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm building a Backbone.js based app and face a strange issue.

At a certain point the app requests a collection resource and inside Chrome (and Safari) I get an error like that:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mydomain.net/v1/foos/00000d/bars/000014/boots Origin http://localhost:3501 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Ok, CORS issue I thought and blamed my API. Then requested this very resource via CURL:

```
curl -i -H'Accept: application/json' -H'X-Auth-Token: pAWp5hrCmXA83GgFzgHC' -XOPTIONS 'http://api.mydomain.net/v1/foos/00000d/bars/000014/boots'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status: 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token
Content-Length: 0
```

looks good, now the GET:

```
curl -i -H'Accept: application/json' -H'X-Auth-Token: pAWp5hrCmXA83GgFzgHC' -XGET 'http://api.mydomain.net/v1/foos/00000d/bars/000014/boots'
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Status: 204
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
```

In case I request boots collection that contain at least one object, everything works fine. The CORS headers my server responds with arr totally fine as I think. So why do the browsers report a cross origin resource problem?

Is it due to the content type `text/plain` of my 204 responses?

Preflight (OPTIONS) request in dev tools:
[image: OPTIONS]

Request headers of aborted response:
[image: GET]

Comment: Make sure that the problem is really caused by CORS, and not some server-side failure. Run Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag and carefully inspect the server's response.

Comment: Unfortunately most recent Chrome (non-dev) on OSX dies when started with that command line switch.

Comment: Check your server's error logs.

Comment: Serverlog is fine: Started GET "/v1/foos/00000d/bars/000014/boots" for 93.219.xxx.yyy at 2012-11-10 11:33:04 +0100
  Processing by V1::BootsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"foo_id"=>"00000d", "bar_id"=>"000014"}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 204 No Content in 7ms (Views: 0.4ms)

Comment: So, the server is not the issues cause.

Comment: Whats making me ask, ist the OPTIONS request which states on the server side: Processing by ApplicationController#options as "*/*". So may the unspecified Content-Type of the response to the OPTIONS request cause the problem?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the Devtool's Network tab? (to check if you're including any unhandled non-[simple](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-header) headers in your request.

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/2P1M392K450r

Comment: Well, and thats the OPTIONS request before: http://cl.ly/image/3f0u440F0V22

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to also include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers of the second request. That's not a client-side issue, but a backend one.

This behaviour is in accordance with the [CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), applied in the following explanation ([section 7.1.5 "Cross-Origin Request with Preflight"](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0)):

1. Preflight request ([details](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight) omitted)
2. "Set the [cross-origin request status](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-status) to preflight complete."
3. "This is the actual request. (...) observe the request rules below while making the request."

   - <s>If the response has an HTTP status code of 301, 302, 303, or 307</s> *Not applicable*
   - <s>If the end user cancels the request</s> *Not applicable*
   - <s>If there is a network error</s> *Not applicable*
   - Otherwise
     Perform a [resource sharing check](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check). If it returns fail, apply the cache and network error steps.

**Your** request already fails at the first step of the [resource sharing check](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check):

1. If the response includes zero or more than one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header values, return fail and terminate this algorithm.

---

I provide a simple NodeJS example illustrating your problem.
Your current backend behaves like:

```
require('http').createServer(function(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'OPTIONS') { // Handle preflight
        response.writeHead(200, {
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Foo"
        });
    } else {                           // Handle actual requests
        response.writeHead(204, {
          //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        });
    }
    response.end();
}).listen(12345);
```

Now, make the request and experience a **failure**:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
x.open('GET', 'http://localhost:12345');
x.setRequestHeader('X-Foo','header to trigger preflight');
x.send();
```

Go back to the code I provided, and enable the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, and test again. Your request will now succeed.

Comment: The 204 simply did not include the CORS headers ... thx for all your effort and the great answer!